# Testing Hive + spark python programs locally?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, apache-spark, hive

I'd like to develop programs with spark + hive and unit test them locally.

Is there a way to get hive to run in-process? Or something else that will facilitate unit testing?

I'm using python 2.7 on Mac

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: since spark 2, it is possible to create a local hive metastore that can be used in test. the original answer is at the bottom.

---

from the [spark sql programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables):

> When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive
>   support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore,
>   support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions. **Users who do
>   not have an existing Hive deployment can still enable Hive support.
>   When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically
>   creates metastore_db in the current directory and creates a directory
>   configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory
>   spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is
>   started.** Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in
>   hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use
>   spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in
>   warehouse. You may need to grant write privilege to the user who
>   starts the Spark application.

basically what it means that if you don't configure hive, spark will create a metastore for you, and store it on local disk.

2 configuration that you should be a aware of:

- `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` - a spark config, points to where the data in the table is stored on the disk, ie: `"/path/to/test/folder/warehouse/"`
- `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` - this is a hive config, and should be set in `hive-site.xml` (or as a system property), ie: `"jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/path/to/test/folder/metastore_db;create=true"`

those are not mandatory (since they have a default value), but sometimes it is convenient to set them explicitly

you need to make sure to clean the test folder between tests, to have a clean env for each suite

---

Original Answer:

I would recommend installing a [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) box that contains the a full (small) hadoop cluster in a VM on your machine.

you can find a ready vagrant here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-install-a-virtual-apache-hadoop-cluster-with-vagrant-and-cloudera-manager/

That way your test could run in the same environment as production

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: It might be a pain to setup a vagrant box at the beginning, but it is worth it in the long run, especially if you work in a team, and want everybody to have a simple way to setup their test env